# Should two quarter rests always be written as half rest?

Tags: notation, engraving, rests

I am putting a piece one of my friends wrote for our middle school band into Sibelius to format the parts and score correctly. The rests are, currently, all quarter rests. Should I change these to half rests whenever there are two in a row or are there times when I should leave them as two quarters for the purpose of clarity/counting? Most of what I'm asking about are pairs of rests on 1,2 and on 3,4 of 4/4 measures.

Comment: It depends in whether you intend to play those rests *legato* or *staccato*;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pairs of quarter-rests that add up to half a bar should be changed to a half-rest. That applies to your 1,2 and 3,4 beats situation.

But rests should not usually be combined *across* the middle of the bar, so quarter rests on beats 2,3 should be left as they are.

But there are no "unbreakable rules" here - if it's easier to read a part where a bar is written as quarter-note, half-rest, quarter-note, then write it like that.

Answer (score 0):

In 4/4 or 2/2, two quarter rests spanning the first half or second half of the measure can be combined. It's generally hard to sight read a half rest spanning the middle of the measure. It's a tradition but it really makes things easy to read.

In 6/8, I've never seen half rest. I have seen half rest spanning beats 1&2 or 2&3 in 3/4 time (mostly the former). In 6/2, only pairs of beats 1&2 or 3&4 or 5&6 are spanned by half rests.

The general rule is that rests (and notes) should reflect the time signature. Irregularities are generally indicated by slurs to mark phrasing.

Comment: Slurs indicate that slurring is required.  BEAMING can be used to indicate rhythm groups.